# $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^2} \sum_{i=1}^n\ln( i^{1/i}) $ =?

Tags: limits

What is the value of the following limit?
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \ln (i^{1/i}) .$$

Comment: If you write the term as $$\frac{\log i}{i},$$ does that help you find the limit?

Comment: That was something I was able to do, but was unable to carry on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm arguing informally here.

Since
$\ln i^{1/i}
=\frac{\ln i}{i}
$,
the sum is
$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\ln i}{i}$.

Since 
$(\ln^2 x)'
=2 \frac{\ln x}{x}
$,
$\int \frac{\ln x\ dx}{x}
=\frac12 \ln^2 x
$.

We then get
$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\ln i}{i}
\sim \int_1^n \frac{\ln x\ dx}{x}
=\frac12 \ln^2 x \big|_1^n
\sim \frac12 \ln^2 n
$,
so the limit is $\frac12$.

Comment: Can probably be made rigorous using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.

Comment: Or just squeeze it.

Comment: "just squeeze it". How ??

Answer (score 0):

**hint:**  $$\int \dfrac{1}{x} ln(x)={ln^2(x)\over 2}$$ and

$$ \int_2^nf(x)dx\geq\sum_2^n f(n)\geq \int_2^n f(x-1) dx$$ for $f(x)=\dfrac  {ln^2(x)} 2$ 
and  by applying the squeze theorem we are done.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : you are right, I will edit my answer.